# Need help understanding code example from Godot Docs

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am trying to learn collisions in Godot 3D, but I am having some difficulty understanding this code example from the Godot Docs here:  [Godot Docs - Advanced Vectors](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-docs/blob/master/tutorials/math/vectors_advanced.rst)

How can I understand this code? Specifically, in the section that reads `if (min_A > max_B or min_B > max_A):`,  what specifically is going on that allows the engine to determine that the two meshes are NOT overlapping or colliding?

Code example from the site I provided a link to is here:

```
var overlapping = true

for p in planes_of_A:
var all_out = true
for v in points_of_B:
    if (p.distance_to(v) < 0):
        all_out = false
        break

if (all_out):
    # a separating plane was found
    # do not continue testing
    overlapping = false
    break

if (overlapping):
# only do this check if no separating plane
# was found in planes of A
for p in planes_of_B:
    var all_out = true
    for v in points_of_A:
        if (p.distance_to(v) < 0):
            all_out = false
            break

    if (all_out):
        overlapping = false
        break

if (overlapping):
for ea in edges_of_A:
    for eb in edges_of_B:
        var n = ea.cross(eb)
        if (n.length() == 0):
            continue

        var max_A = -1e20 # tiny number
        var min_A = 1e20 # huge number

        # we are using the dot product directly
        # so we can map a maximum and minimum range
        # for each polygon, then check if they
        # overlap.

        for v in points_of_A:
            var d = n.dot(v)
            max_A = max(max_A, d)
            min_A = min(min_A, d)

        var max_B = -1e20 # tiny number
        var min_B = 1e20 # huge number

        for v in points_of_B:
            var d = n.dot(v)
            max_B = max(max_B, d)
            min_B = min(min_B, d)

        if (min_A > max_B or min_B > max_A):
            # not overlapping!
            overlapping = false
            break

    if (not overlapping):
        break

if (overlapping):
print("Polygons collided!")
```

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, this is not a Godot question, more of a general game engine and vector maths question. This is a common method of detecting collisions using cross and dot products to determine whether or not a point in one polygon is inside of another polygon.

If you know the definitions of the cross and dot products, I'd encourage you to grab a piece of paper, draw two arbitrary colliding polygons and work through this example step-by-step to see what exactly Godot is doing to determine collisions. If you don't know the definitions of cross and dot products, KhanAcademy has some excellent introductions.

The being said, if you're trying to develop games, you should ignore this example as it is a very specific detail of the game's internal physics engine that you don't need to know to leverage the physics engine to its full extent. Skip the code, open up Godot, make a bunch of collision objects, play with them and see how they behave, then maybe create some simple collision detection examples in GDScript using Godot's signals if you want to get a feel for how collision detection works in Godot.

This example is only really important if you're interested in learning how to build your own game engine. Which, if you are, there are better places to learn about how collision detection is implemented than the Godot Docs! I'd reccomend *Game Engine Architecture* by Jason Gregory (ISBN: 9781568814131).